# If I use "array.splice()", are the removed elements deleted from memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory

I'm writing some functions to remove elements from arrays. I'm using `splice` for this, and it is working just fine. However, I am not 100% sure as to whether or not splice completely removes the removed elements from memory, or if they are still instantiated somewhere that I am unaware of.

Does anybody know one way or another? If it does not remove from memory, should I do something along the lines of:

```
delete array[index];
array.splice(index,1);
```

Comment: `delete` is redundant in your code.

Comment: @zerkms `delete` is not used in my code :) read the context right before.

Comment: in the example you provided `delete` is redundant. Now better?

Comment: yes :) much better :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no other references to those objects within your system, then it will be removed.

But if you have another active reference to that object somewhere in your code then it will not be removed.

Comment: what if the element at that index is an object with a whole bunch of properties, and something somewhere references one of said properties?

Comment: @thisissami: you don't reference to a properties but to an objects. If an object is unreachable - it's a candidate for garbage collecting. That's it.

Comment: @thisissami I think https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Example shows how it should work...